# Cassandra 3.0 is not accepting Java 11 installation

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I am trying to launch Cassandra 3, but it gives message:

> Cassandra 3.0 and later require Java 8u40 or later.

I have Java 11 installed.

```
>java -version
java version "11.0.11" 2021-04-20 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.11+9-LTS-194)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.11+9-LTS-194, mixed mode)
```

JAVA_HOME is set to this installation.

Why does Cassandra still asks for Java 8 or higher?

Comment: The later here would refer to the Java 8 build level, 1.8.0_40 would be quite an old build of Java 8

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cassandra 3.x doesn't support Java 11. Only Cassandra 4.0 will support Java 11 - see [docs](https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/new/java11.html).
You need to install Java 8 to run Cassandra on your machine to run Cassandra 3.x

Comment: Thanks for input. Message is a bit misleading with word 'later'. Another problem is that Cassandra 4 doesn't support Windows.

Comment: yeah, agree about misleading message... Regarding Windows - now, when Docker is available it makes no sense to support non-production platform that isn't used by any of developers

Comment: Yup, docker makes it easy. In my case I actually want to playaround with codebase. I tried building from codebase, but there too batch file is not generated in bin folder.